# Animate dynamic elements with delay in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I got an iron-ajax call who retrieves x amount of elements that are displayed with a dom-repeat. I would like to for example run scale up animation on each of the elements but I want to do this sequential, i.e wait for the element to finish its animation before drawing the next on.

How do I achieve this in Polymer?

Comment: i think it should be possible with `neon-animations`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways in which i think this can be achieved using `neon-animation` are

1. Use `timing` object to set `delay` and `duration`
2. Manually play the animations using `playAnimation` function

Comment: The question I'm asking is how to play the animations in sequence on dynamically created objects

Comment: What i was thinking was to set duration and delay dynamically to each node

Comment: And how do you access the individual nodes while they are being rendered?

Comment: Try listening on `dom-change` event